# Gradle settings file change keeps creating directories

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I'm migrating my Android projects from Eclipse to Android Studio, and it has not been a smooth process. I'm not very familiar with Gradle, and I'm running into a very strange issue.

In my project's root directory, I have a `settings.gradle` file. I have a library project that I'm including with my main module. On my first attempt to correctly include this, this is what I put in the `settings.gradle` file:

```
include ':app,:libraries:betterpickers-library'
```

I now know that this is the incorrect syntax, and I have since changed it to

```
include ':app',':libraries:betterpickers-library'
```

However, even after I've made the change, cleaned, and rebuilt the project, Android Studio continuously will create a folder in my root directory named `app,` with a subdirectories of `libraries` and `betterpickers-library`. If I delete this folder, it's regenerated right away.

Does anyone have any idea how I can prevent that folder from being created? It seems to be an artifact of my original incorrect `settings.gradle` file.

Comment: The folder still comes back. Is that different than `Build -> Clean Project`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

1. Close your project
2. Back up your project
3. Delete all the .iml files and the .idea folder
4. Reimport your project

Comment: I figured it out right before you posted this it seems. I think you had the right idea though, as the problem was in the .idea folder.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by editing the `.idea/modules.xml` file.

There was still a `<module>` item for the incorrect entry I had in the `settings.gradle` file earlier. Once I deleted that line, my `settings.gradle` became blank. I entered in the correct `include` statement and all is well now.

Comment: Your answer ia almost same as Scott's answer so instead of putting your own answer you should accept the answer given by Scott.